# Correct syntax for a lambda expression which gets any number of arguments in Scheme

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket

In Scheme you can define the following procedure:

```
(define (proc . vars)
        (display (length vars)))
```

This will allow you to send any amount of args to proc. But when I try to do it this way:

```
(define proc (lambda (. vars)
        (display (length vars))))
```

I get the following error:

> read: illegal use of "."

I can't seem to find the correct syntax for a lambda expression which gets any number of arguments. Ideas?

(I'm using DrScheme, version 209, with language set to PLT(Graphical))

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I strongly encourage you to upgrade to the latest version of DrScheme, now called DrRacket.  You can download it here:
  http://racket-lang.org/

Comment: @SamTH The version of DrScheme I used was dictated by my university, but thanks, anyway - I may finish reading SICP on my free time and use this version instead...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first argument of `lambda` is the list of arguments:

```
(define proc (lambda vars
    (display (length vars))))

(proc 1 2 4) ; 3
(proc) ; 0
```

Comment: Lambda is a special form, and it's a mistake to call the second thing in a lambda form the "first argument". Sorry, captain pedantic here.

Comment: @John: What would you call it?

Comment: I would probably call it "the second element of the lambda form." The problem with the word "argument" is that it's inextricably associated with function calling.

Answer (score 6):

The key insight to understanding the `(lambda args ...)` syntax (that other posters have helpfully posted already) is that a lone non-list item (in this case, `args`) is a degenerate improper list. Example:

```
(define a '(arg1 arg2 . rest))
a                   ; => (arg1 arg2 . rest) (improper list of length 2)
(cdr a)             ; => (arg2 . rest)      (improper list of length 1)
(cdr (cdr a))       ; => rest               (improper list of length 0)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the degenerate list `(a1 a2 . args)` would, without a1 and a2, simply be `args`. A degenerate list is one that lacks the ending pair with a nil.

Comment: @Tim: The proper term for a list that lacks a `'()` end is an _improper list_. A _degenerate_ improper list is one that ceases to even look like a list, not even an improper one.

Comment: I didn't know of the distinction between _improper_ and _degenerate_. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should omit the parentheses on lambda's argument list to denote a variable number of arguments:

```
(define proc (lambda vars
    (display (length vars))))
```